# goto в другой if

Tags: c#

Как перескочить на `goto` через `if/else` ?

```
if (File.Exists("File.txt"))
{
   goto First;
}
if (....)
else
{
  First:
        // что-то выполняется тут...
}
```

Мне пишет что:

> В области видимости оператора goto отсутствует метка First

Comment: Оператор goto в c# - это рудимент, постарайтесь его избегать.

Comment: Покажите ваш код, зачем вам из одного `if` прыгать во второй?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Никак.

[`goto`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/statements#the-goto-statement) позволяет перемещаться только во внешний блок, но не внутрь какого-то блока.

В данном случае идет попытка переместиться *внутрь* `if`, поэтому это явно противоречит разрешенному использованию.

Comment: Забавно, но на самом низком уровне (инструкции цп) таких ограничений нет. Может оно и к лучшему.

Comment: @aepot, это ограничение именно на уровне языка. Даже в msil меньше [ограничений](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.br_s?view=net-5.0)

Answer (score 0):

Вот так:

```
   if (File.Exists("File.txt"))
    {
       // что-то выполняется тут...
    }
    if (....)
    else
    {
        // что-то выполняется тут...
    }
```

При этом "что-то выполняется тут" лучше поместить в отдельную функцию.

Comment: Я просто думал, можно ли перепрыгивать с `if` на ``if через `goto`. теперь понял что нельзя, там по другому надо. Смысл был в том чтобы из одного начала перепрыгнуть в другое...